# nhibernate class implementation based on value

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm creating a blog library using nHibernate and I have a **BlogEntry** class that has a CreatedBy property of type **User** (User is an abstract class). The two concrete implementations of the User class are **RegisteredUser** and **UnknownUser**.  I'd like nHibernate to instantiate **UnknownUser** class if the value in the CreatedBy field is null. If it is not null I'd like it to instantiate **RegisteredUser**.

Is this possible with nHibernate? and what should my mapping file look like if it is?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out. I watched the video [here](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/screencasts/Summer%20of%20Nhibernate%20Session%2011.wmv) on modeling inheritance in nHibernate. I needed to create subclass nodes in my User mapping file and create a discriminator column in the table.